# How to create cron job that is executing every 3 months?

Tags: cron, hangfire

I am using [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io) in ASP.NET Core for [Cron (recurring) Jobs](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html), and I need to create a job that runs every three months starting from a given start date.

So if the start date was 15-Nov-2019, it should run on 15-Nov-2019, 15-Feb-2020, 15-May-2020 and so on and so forth.

And I need it to run every 3 months **forever**.

So I tried the following cron expression for this: "0 0 15 11/3 ?" or "0 0 15 11/3 *"

But after testing it on [this translating site](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_15_11/3_*), it tells me that it will run on the following dates:

2019-11-15
2020-11-15
2021-11-15
2022-11-15
2023-11-15

[image: my cron expression after testing it]

So, if that is true, then how to make it run every three months starting from 15-Nov-2019 as described above and keep running forever?

Comment: you should try 0 0 15 1/3 *  see https://crontab.guru/#0_0_15_1/3_*

Comment: @jbl That runs in Jan/Apr/Jul/Oct instead of Feb/May/Aug/Nov, though.

Comment: @BenjaminW.yes, I didn't notice that the months were relevant in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The month field in cron takes a number between 1 and 12; depending on the cron implementation used, you could use an explicit list for the month field:

```
0 0 15 2,5,8,11 *
```

or a range with a step:

```
0 0 15 2-12/3 *
```

crontab.guru seems to support a single value with a step as well, but the [crontab man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) doesn't mention this style, so it might or might not work:

```
0 0 15 2/3 *
```

---

If you want to be able to set this up more than three months before you want it to run for the first time, you have to manually check the date; in shell (using GNU `date`), you would do something like this:

```
0 0 15 2-12/3 * [ $(date +%%s) -gt $(date -d '2019-11-01' +%%s) ] && yourcommand
```

This compares the current date to November 1st, 2019; if it is greater than that, the command is run.

Comment: thanks for your answer, anyway, I am using Hangfire in ASP.NET, not Unix. But any way, your answer "0 0 15 2-12/3 *" will fix it for the start date described above (15-Nov-2019), but not for a start date like 15-Jun-2020, if I used a cron expression like "0 0 15 3-12/3 *", then it will from 2019-12-15, 2019-3-15, 2019-6-15, etc... sorry for not clarifying that in my question, I am not sure, but may be I should handle this another way (like creating a scheduled job that will insert a cron job with "0 0 15 3-12/3 *" on 15-Jun-2019. What do you think?

Comment: @HusseinDahir In whatever you're running, you could check the current date and only continue if it's past the date you want to start. Cron alone can't handle "start at arbitrary date in the future".

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution is to use the following command:

```
0 0 15 */3 *
```

It is very straight forward.Here's the output for your satisfaction from crontab.guru website
[output of cron job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiAiP.png)

Comment: Yes, thanks - this is the way to go right here!